# VSTO C# custom form if i forget add attachment to email

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, email-attachments

When I press a custom button on my form, I need to check if the user has forgotten to add an attachment, otherwise the msbox must appear and stop sending the e-mail until the attachment is inserted.

```
public partial class AddItemsForm : Form
    {
        public AddItemsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // If Attachment.Add() = false
        // show msgox
        }
```

UPDATE I

`form.cs`

```
    private DialogResult GetAttachmentsInfo(MailItem mailItem)
    {
        StringBuilder attachmentInfo = new StringBuilder();
        Attachments mailAttachments = mailItem.Attachments;
        if (mailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(" ", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        } else {
            return DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }

 private void Btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetAttachmentsInfo(mailItem);
    }
```

Error in Outlook after press the button : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

any ideas ?

UPDATE II `error`

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at OutlookControll.Form1.GetAttachmentsInfo(MailItem mailItem) ChooseFormSend.cs:line 33
   at OutlookControll.Form1.Btn_standard_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) ChooseFormSend.cs:line 74
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `MailItem.Attachments.Count == 0`.
Or, if there were, for example, image files, check if the number of attachments is the same as when the message was created.

Comment: added this to my Form.cs:        ```` private DialogResult GetAttachmentsInfo(MailItem mailItem)
        {
            StringBuilder attachmentInfo = new StringBuilder();
            Attachments mailAttachments = mailItem.Attachments;
            if (mailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                return MessageBox.Show(".", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            } else {
                return DialogResult.OK;
            }


        }```` and error: ````Object reference not set to an instance of an object.````

Comment: And which object is null?

Comment: Error in Update II

Comment: So what is on line 33? As you step through your code, which object is null?

Comment: ````Attachments mailAttachments = mailItem.Attachments;````

Comment: So that means mailItem variable is null. Is that what you are seeing in the debugger as you step through your code?

Answer (score 0):

there is solution:

```
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();

        if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem inspectorMailItem)
        {
            String Subject = inspectorMailItem.Subject;
            String EmailAddress = inspectorMailItem.To;

            if (inspectorMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Attachment");

                this.Hide();
```